# How to apply series in isocalendar function in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following table:

```
Time                     
2016-09-10T23:20:00.000000000
2016-08-10T23:20:00.000000000
2016-09-10T23:20:00.000000000
2017-09-10T23:20:00.000000000
2016-09-10T23:20:00.000000000
```

I wish to used **isocalender** to get the work weeks, so any ideas can share me?

```
Time                               WW
2016-01-01T23:20:00.000000000      201601
2016-01-01T23:20:00.000000000      201601
2016-01-01T23:20:00.000000000      201601
2017-01-01T23:20:00.000000000      201701
2018-01-01T23:20:00.000000000      201801
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
#convert column to datetime
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

#simplier solution with strftime
df['WW'] = df['Time'].dt.strftime('%G-%V')
#solution with isocalendar
df['WW1'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: str(x.isocalendar()[0]) + '-' + 
                                       str(x.isocalendar()[1]).zfill(2))
print (df)
                 Time       WW      WW1
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00  2016-52  2016-52 <- changed datetime
1 2016-08-10 23:20:00  2016-32  2016-32
2 2016-09-10 23:20:00  2016-36  2016-36
3 2017-09-10 23:20:00  2017-36  2017-36
4 2016-09-10 23:20:00  2016-36  2016-36
```

Thank you @Fierr for correct `'%Y-%V'` to `'%G-%V'`.

Comment: hi, if my weeks is 1, then anyway can have a output like 01?

Comment: I dont test it, give me a sec.

Comment: You can use `zfill` function like `df['WW1'] = datetimes.apply(lambda x: str(x.isocalendar()[0]) + '-' +  str(x.isocalendar()[1]).zfill(2))`

Comment: Wouldn't advice to use strftime: seems incorrect to me. Example: print(dt.datetime(2017,1,1).strftime('%Y-%V')). Which gives 2017-52.

Comment: @Fierr - Yop, I agree. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35129654)

Comment: Correction to the above: I do suggest to use strftime, but with the ISO-8601 implementation of YEAR-WEEK, which is '%G-%V' instead of '%Y-%V'. %G is the ISO year equivalent of %Y.